# Is $D^2\times S^1$ compact?

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homology-cohomology

I'm studying about the homology group and I have a question that  denote $D^2$ the closed unit disk and $S^1$ the circle.The homology groups of a 3-dimension manifold $D^2\times S^1$ are $H_0(D^2\times S^1)=H_1(D^2\times S^1)\cong\Bbb Z$ and $H_n(D^2\times S^1)=0$ if $n= 2,3,...$ since $D^2\times S^1$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1$.But I find a theorem form a Japanese text:

Let $M$ be a n-dimension compact connected manifold and then there is a nonnegative integer $l$ such that either $H_n(M)\cong\Bbb Z $ and $H_{n-1}(M)\cong\Bbb Z^l$ or $H_n(M)=0$ and $H_{n-1}(M)\cong(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)\oplus \Bbb Z^l$.

This theorem is not valid for $D^2\times S^1$ but why? $D^2\times S^1$ is clearly connected so it is not compact? But it is closed and bounded in $\Bbb R^3$ so it is compact.
Could you plaese tell me where did I make a mistake? Thank you!

Comment: The Cartesian product of two compact spaces is always compact.

Comment: It's not a manifold. The closed disk $D^2$ is not a manifold but a manifold with boundary. The points $S^1\subseteq D^2$ have neighbourhoods in $D^2$ that aren't homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ but to a closed half-plane. This makes it so that $D^2\times S^1$ is not a manifold either.

Comment: @Jakobian probably means to say that $D^2\times S^1$ is a manifold with boundary, whereas the statement you are referring to applies only to *closed* manifolds (i.e. compact without boundary). The terminology can be confusing when learning the subject.

Comment: @Jakobian Why not an official answer?

Comment: @PaulFrost I don't feel like writing a lengthy answer and elaborating, but if you do then feel free to post an answer below

Comment: I suggest changing the title of this post to "Is $D^2 \times S^1$ a manifold?"

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

> This theorem is not valid for $D^2\times S^1$ but why? $D^2\times S^1$ is clearly connected so it is not compact?

It is compact. However $D^2\times S^1$ **is not a manifold**. At least not in the sense of the theorem. $D^2\times S^1$ is a manifold with (nonempty) boundary. But the theorem refers to manifolds without boundary, which is the usual understanding of the word "manifold" on its own.

This sounds like a small difference, but as the example above shows: not so small.

Comment: Thank you so much!